# Embedding of $S^1\times [0, 1]$ into $S^1\times S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

How can I construct an embedding of $S^1\times [0, 1]$ into $S^1\times S^1$?

I tried to write $S^1=[0, 1]/\sim$ where $0\sim 1$ and I defined $f$ setting: $$f([x], t)=([x], [e^{2\pi it}]),$$ but I guess this map is not injective.

A result that might be useful is the following:

If $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is an injective continuous map from a compact space into a Hausdorff space then $f$ is an embedding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find an embedding $f:[0,1]\to S^1$, then you get an embedding $id \times f:S^1\times [0,1]\to S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: I guess $f:[0, 1]\longrightarrow S^1$ given by $f(t)=e^{\pi it}$ will work out, won't it?

Comment: @PtF: Exactly. Intuitively, you've made sure not to have $[0,1]$ "wrap around"  $S^1$ too far.